# QMouseEvent is of type 5? What is type 5?

Tags: python, pyqt, qmouseevent

I have a Widget that has mouseTracking set to `True` and the following code prints 5, even though I'm not pressing any buttons. Additionally type 5 isn't mentioned in the [MouseButton enum docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#MouseButton-enum).
So what is type 5 and why is the mouseEvent of type 5?

The code:

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent) -> None:
    print(event.type())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing with the [`type()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#type) property of **all** QEvents.

In fact, in the [`Type`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum) enum of QEvent, `MouseMove` has value 5.

If you want to check the *pressed buttons of a mouse move event*, use the [`buttons()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#buttons) property of QMouseEvent.

Note that `button()` and `buttons()` are *not* the same thing:

- `button()` returns the buttons that *cause* the event, which means that it will always be `0` for mouse move events, since the event is originated by the movement, not a button pressure;
- `buttons()` returns the buttons when the event was *generated* (and you're probably interested in this one);

Finally, `mouseMoveEvent()` is always called for widgets that have [`mouseTracking`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop) enabled. This happens by default in some special cases (usually for scroll area based classes), for instance in a QGraphicsView with interactive items.

Comment: Thanks! I just confused `type()` and `buttons()`.